# How many times does Sneak Attack damage apply with several attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, sneak-attack

I've designed for a campaign a duo of rogues. My character is as Sniper, and his follower is a Knife Mistress. Couple of questions about them.

Our party is about to ambush several trolls. My Sniper will hide near their camp, and shoot the weakest one when fight begins. His follower will then rush the troll and slice him in several pieces.

My Knife Mistress is high enough to have BAB +6/+1, is dual-welding daggers and has the Improved Two-Weapons Fighting feat. I get 4 attacks (+8, +8, +3, +3).

Now, does she deal Sneak Stab's damages on each attack (×4), only on main hand attack (×2), on only once per round (×1), as in 5e?

Comment: Also, I think you're misunderstanding how Improved Two Weapon Fighting works.  At +6/+1, you're getting two main hand attacks.  Improved two weapon fighting allows you to also take two offhand attacks.  That totals four attacks.  Counting the -2 to all attacks from two-weapon fighting, these attacks are at +4/+4/-1/-1 before apply your stat bonus (Str, or Dex with Weapon Finesse) or anything like Weapon Focus or masterwork weapon modifier.

Comment: Please adjust your question to take into account gatherer818's points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The rogue's attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target.

“Anytime” means exactly that: you get the sneak attack for each and every attack that meets the requirements of triggering a sneak attack. There is no cooldown or frequency limit on sneak attack.

Moreover, not only *can* a rogue trigger sneak attack as many times as she is eligible to, she *must* to maintain a significant combat presence. The damage of a single sneak attack is simply too small to make the rogue much of a threat, particularly at higher levels.

Note that some ways of triggering sneak attack invalidate themselves after the first attack, however. For example, most forms of stealth leave it very difficult to continue to be hidden after the first attack (in fact, most make it hard to make even the one attack, but the rules for stealth are kind of a mess). The *invisibility* spell is another obvious situation where after making one attack (ending the *invisibility* spell), your remaining attacks may not continue to trigger sneak attack.

But in other situations, like flanking, you can and should get sneak attack as many times as possible. This fact is the very reason *why* rogues like two-weapon fighting so much, to get more sneak attack in.